# Invalid input syntax for type numeric: "(0.0000000000000000,8)"

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql

I created this PL/pgSQL function in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.diploma_cal_grade(
    amk integer)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    a2 integer;
    mo1_upox_sum double precision; 
    mo1_epil_sum double precision;
    weig1 integer;
    weig2 integer;
    upox_sum numeric;
    epil_sum numeric;
    dipl_g integer ;
    cour_g numeric ;
    fin_g numeric ;
BEGIN

-----SUM(final_grade*weight)= double precition variable-------
mo1_upox_sum=(Select SUM(final_grade*weight)
        FROM ("Course" c join "Register" r USING(course_code)) natural join "Diploma" d
        where d.amka=amk and r.register_status='pass' and c.obligatory='true');

weig1=(Select SUM(weight)
        FROM ("Course" c join "Register" r USING(course_code)) natural join "Diploma" d
        where d.amka=amk and r.register_status='pass' and c.obligatory='true');

--------double precition/integer        
upox_sum=(mo1_upox_sum/weig1):: numeric;


a2=(select distinct g.min_courses from "Graduation_rules" g); --for help

-----give me a double precition variable
mo1_epil_sum=(select_courses_maxgrad(amk));
-----give me an integer----     
weig2=(select SUM(mk.we)
        from(select weight as we
        from "Course" c join "Register" r USING(course_code)
        where r.amka=amk and c.obligatory='false' and  r.register_status='pass' 
        order by r.final_grade DESC
        Limit a2)as mk);


--------double precition/integer        
epil_sum=(mo1_epil_sum/weig2):: numeric;

---give me an integer-----
dipl_g=(select thesis_grade from "Diploma" where amka=2);

cour_g=(((upox_sum+epil_sum)/2)*0,8);
fin_g=((dipl_g*0,2)+cour_g);
RETURN fin_g:: numeric(4,2);

END;
$BODY$;
```

Trying to execute it, I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "(0.0000000000000000,8)"
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function diploma_cal_grade(integer) line 45 at assignment
> SQL state: 22P02
> ```

I'm not sure why; I've cast my values to `numeric` many times and I've changed my variables to the `numeric` type, but to no avail.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [@Laurenz said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50049970/939860).

#### But why the "strange" error message?

Your **syntax error** (`0,8` instead of `0.8` in `cour_g=(((upox_sum+epil_sum)/2)*0,8);`) is obfuscated by the added, **gratuitous parentheses** which are interpreted as [`ROW` constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) - the leading keyword `ROW` is optional noise.

What you see in the error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "(0.0000000000000000,8)"
> ```

... is a *row expression* consisting of the fields: `0.0000000000000000` and `8`.
Without the misleading parentheses, the assignment:

```
cour_g=((upox_sum+epil_sum)/2)*0,8;  -- still incorrect: 0,8
```

... would have produced a different (more revealing) error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  query "SELECT ((upox_sum+epil_sum)/2)*0,8" returned 2 columns
> ```

because the comma (`,`) is interpreted as column separator.

<sub>This message also reveals that PL/pgSQL evaluates every bare expression with a (basic and fast) `SELECT` statement internally. The language is basically a wrapper around the core SQL engine. This explains why assignments are slightly more expensive than one might expect coming from other PLs.</sub>

Your original statement is equivalent to the more verbose `ROW` syntax:

```
cour_g=ROW(((upox_sum + epil_sum)/2)*0,8);  -- still incorrect: 0,8
```

... which is *functionally* equivalent to:

```
cour_g=(SELECT ROW(((upox_sum + epil_sum)/2)*0,8));  -- still incorrect: 0,8
```

Both result in the same error message you observed.

Or:

```
cour_g=(SELECT ((upox_sum + epil_sum)/2)*0,8);  -- still incorrect: 0,8
```

With a different (already more revealing) error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
> ```

The parentheses around the nested, explicit `SELECT` are required. If you drop the unneeded `SELECT`, drop the wrapping parentheses with it, or they are interpreted as `ROW` constructor (with or without the noise word `ROW`).

So use:

```
cour_g := (upox_sum + epil_sum) / 2 * 0.8;
```

The parentheses around `((upox_sum+epil_sum)/2)` are also superfluous because `*` and `/` share the same [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) and are evaluated left-to-right anyway. But in this case, the added parentheses are harmless noise (that may or may not help readability).

Or simplify to:

```
cour_g := (upox_sum + epil_sum) * 0.4;
```

That said, since assignments are comparatively expensive in PL/pgSQL, try to adopt a programming style with fewer assignments.
And not all gratuitous parentheses are harmless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
cour_g=(((upox_sum+epil_sum)/2)*0,8);
```

The decimal separator always has to be a period, so you have to use `0.8` and not `0,8`.